# Mountain Lion : Take an image of OS X joined to a domain

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I've been using MacBook Pro. My question is how to capture a disk image of a Mac running Mountain Lion that is currently bound to an Active or Open Directory? What do you recommended for that?

Comment: Are you asking how to capture an image of a Mac running Mountain Lion that is currently bound to an Active or Open Directory?  I assume if so you would like to keep the binding in place in the image, so that when Macs are imaged with the captured image they are automatically bound to the domain as well?

Comment: Are you asking how to capture an image of a Mac running Mountain Lion that is currently bound to an Active or Open Directory? Yes I want to take it to an external drive. During crash I want to restore it.

Comment: Using your Recovery Disk (hold Option at boot, select Recovery) you can use Disk Utility to create an image of your Mountain Lion system, naming and saving it to an external hard drive.  The binding information should remain intact in the image so no other considerations would be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding should remain in place when the image is captured.

1. Boot to your Recovery partition by holding <kbd>option</kbd> while powering on your Mac, then selecting Recovery
2. From the *Mac OS X Utilities* window choose Disk Utility
3. In Disk Utility, choose **File > New > Disk Image from "Macintosh HD"**
4. You will be asked to name the image (**Save As**) and select a destination (**Where**).  Fill in a name and select your external hard drive as the destination.
5. Once your image is created, which can take a long time depending on how much data is on the Mac, it will appear in the left hand pane of Disk Utility.
6. Select the image from the left hand pane in Disk Utility and from the menu bar choose **Images > Scan Image for Restore**.  This will scan the image and append the info for Disk Utility to later restore it to a disk as needed.  This process can take a while as well.

My only concern would be re-binding with the proper computer name if you end up restoring the image to a different Mac, this could be accomplished by editing the Active Directory info in Directory Utility.

1. Go to **System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options** and click the **Edit** button next to **Network Accounts**.
   [image]
2. Click on **Open Directory Utility**.
   [image]
3. Click on the lock in the lower left corner of Directory Utility and enter your password when prompted.
4. Double click on **Active Directory**.
   [image]
5. You might take a screenshot of your different settings here, under User Experience, Mappings and Administration, just in case they get wiped out and you have to re-enter them.  You can capture a screenshot of this window by pressing <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> and using the cross hairs to grab the part of the screen you'd like to capture.
6. Click **Unbind** to unbind from the directory.  Make whatever changes you need and then click **Bind** to re-bind the Mac to the directory.  When re-binding you'll need to authenticate as an administrator for the corresponding directory.
   [image]

Comment: like you mentioned if I do restore it to a different MAC how can I edit Active Directory info? Could you please add it your answer? thanks again

Comment: Just added it for you.  Hopefully that helps should you end up needing it.

Comment: thanks for everything. last question is : let's say I joined my domain user I want to give an Ad User local admin permissions I will use this command : 
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a DomainUser -t user admin Am I Correct?

Comment: @Selahattin I'm honestly not sure.  I'll typically give users admin rights directly through System Preferences > Users & Groups.  Alternately you can add an AD group as administrators through the Administration tab in steps 5 & 6 above, in the "Allow administration by:" section.

Comment: Could you please look my another question?thanks. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111111/mountain-lion-password-expiration-for-os-x-that-is-currently-bound-to-an-activ

Comment: @ Mr Rabbit : I'm confused related to Microsoft Product Activation. I will use office for Mac 2011. how can I take an image of MAC?So before office for Mac activation or after?

Comment: @Selahattin I believe that depends on your licensing agreement with Microsoft.  With my workflow, when deploying new Macs, each of which has an Office 2011 license purchased with it, I use DeployStudio to both image the Mac (with a standard Mac OS X image) and then install Microsoft Office and whatever other packages are needed.  It's an automated process but I do retain control over whether or not I install Office.

Comment: I have two question as well. I need urgently answer. 1 - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111351/microsoft-outlook-2010-how-to-migrate-autocomplete-and-contacts-settings  2 - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111210/can-i-open-office-2013-files-in-office-2011-mac